# Translate an object in screen coordinates

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have an object in OpenGL (WebGL), and I'm happy with how it looks like, and would like to move it a bit to the left. However, when I do that, it's perspective changes. I want to keep it exactly like it is, and just get it rendered at a different place.

I am using a fairly standard setup I think, with a projection and a modelview matrix. I tried changing both in various ways, but I can only get my object to move in 3D space, not in flat screen or eye coordinates. Any ideas how to do this (without e.g. rendering to a texture)?

---

Some code excerpts. The functions do the obvious thing, they are taken from a Mozilla WebGL tutorial. I think the exact definition doesn't matter.

```
// set perspective matrix
var perspectiveMatrix = makePerspective(45, 640.0/480.0, 0.1, 100.0);
loadIdentity();
// set modelview matrix
mvTranslate([0, 0, -12]);
mvRotate(rotationAngle, [0, 1, 0]);
// and then I just draw an object...
```

In the vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
```

---

To be honest, I think the concrete code is not so important for this question. Please don't get hung up on it. I could be using Three.js, or DirectX, or a handwritten raytracer. I'll reformulate the question: In the standard formalism, where screen coordinates are calculated from model coordinates by matrix multiplication:

```
u = Perspective * ModelView * x
```

I would like to shift `u` on the screen. I can do that by hand:

```
u.x += deltaX
u.y += deltaY
```

But is there a way to play with the perspective matrix to get the same effect? Is there a "standard" way of introducing transformations in view space? And is there a convenience function in OpenGL to do so?

Comment: Give us some relevant code . Did you use glmatrix engine ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic I'm not sure what code you want to see, the answer should not really depend on it. I added some of the matrix logic anyway. But you can just imagine any simple OpenGL code that draws e.g. a cube. I want to place the cube at the side of the screen, but I don't want to cube to show it's side, or change perspective. I'm am not using glmatrix, but again the answer should not have anything to do with a framework. I am looking for something like: "Multiply your perpective matrix by this" or "use the glShiftScreen magic function".

Comment: And I think I could probably achive it by adding to the x and y coordinates in the shader until I'm satisfied, but I'd like to know the proper, conventional way to do this.

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't show the side. The code you posted is calling a function `makeOrtho`. Maybe you need to post the code to that function as an orthographic matrix should not show the sides.

Comment: @jdm lol, nice edit \s, and that's exactly why posting code is necessary...

Comment: Argh, sorry, I copied the wrong code. That's why I was hesitant to post code. I do use perspective, but it shouldn't matter. I want to translate something in view space, how do I do that? I'm looking for a general, abstract answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I've figured it out. To do a translation, you multiply by a translation matrix (the syntax here is from the Mozilla WebGL tutorial, which uses a combination of sylvester.js and it's own functions, but really just think of it as pseudocode).

The following translates one unit to the left, and one to the side.

```
var shift = Matrix.Translation($V([-1, -1, 0]));
```

If your object is in the middle of the screen (0, 0), and your coordinates go from lower left (-1, -1) to upper right (1, 1), this places the middle of your object in the lower left corner.

The key is now to remember that matrix multiplications are in general non-commutative. So you can't do `perspective x something`, it has to be `something x perspective`. This way, when you act on a model vector, the perspective is applied first, and then your shift:

```
var shiftedPerspectiveMatrix = shift.x(perspectiveMatrix)
```

As a bonus, here is how to do this in pixel coordinates:

```
// for referece:
var perspectiveMatrix = makePerspective(45, 640.0/480.0, 0.1, 100.0);
var trans = Matrix.Translation($V([-1, -1, 0]));
var scale = Matrix.Diagonal([320, 240, 1, 1]);
// move 100 pixels to the left
var viewShift = Matrix.Translation($V([-100, 0, 0]));

let transI = trans.inv();
let scaleI = scale.inv();
var newPerspectiveMatrix = transI.x(scaleI).x(viewShift).x(scale).x(trans).x(perspectiveMatrix);
```

The thing to remember is, when **M** is a matrix, **M<sup>−1</sup> M** is a no-op. After applying **M**, you live in a different coordinate system. So if the transformation **A** you want to apply is defined in that different coordinate system, you can do **x'** = **M<sup>−1</sup> A M x**.

Sorry if I am messing up the order things. It has been a long time since Analytic Geometry and Linear Algebra.

Now what the above code does is, it changes the coordinates into a human-comprehensible system (screen pixels, albeit with the origin in the center), applies the shift I wanted to make, and transforms back to a OpenGL-comprehensible system. Note that application is from right to left, and I undo the operations in the reverse order.